# Returning an array from a method and storing it in a single variable and many ones

Tags: ruby

I have such code:

```
def test1
  ["123", "456"]
end

a = test1
a, b = test1
p a # => "123"
p a + "-" + b  # => "123-456"
```

The methods return an array. Why does `a` equal to its first element and not the entire array?

Comment: If you had swapped the line `a, b = test1` with the next, you would have answered your own question.

Comment: Alex, suppose `d=[1,2]`. Then `a = d` yields `a=>[1,2]`, `a,b = d` yields `a=>1, b=>2`, `a,_ = d` yields `a=>1`, `_,b = d` yields `b=>2`, `a,b,c = d` yields `a=>1, b=>2, c=>nil`.  The (rather ugly) term for `a,b = d` is "disambiguation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how multiple assignment work. If the right side element is an array and there are more than one argument on the left side of assignment, array is being splated. Note that if you do:

```
a = test1
```

`a` is assigned with the whole array.

There are many application of this feature, for example when iterating over a hash:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2}

hash.each do |pair|
  p pair
end
```

Internally hash is an array of 2-element arrays. First element is a key, second a value. Hence the code above will result in:

```
[:a, 1]
[:b, 2]
```

On the beginning of each iteration, ruby makes an assignment like

```
pair = [:a, 1]
```

With multiple assignments, you can then iterate over a hash like:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2}

hash.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value
end
```

Which will change this assignment to:

```
key, value = [:a, 1]
```

Comment: `a is assigned with the whole array.` - as I shown it's assigned to its first element only.

Comment: @Alex - because you reassigned it in the next line. If you remove the second assignment, it will be an array.